# WooCommerce reset quantity before adding to cart (to prevent addition)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

When I add a product quantity of `3` to the cart, it's all good.

But after adding `5` more quantities to the cart, I want to quantity in the cart to be `5` and not `8`.

I want the last quantity sent to override the quantity before, not add to it.

Also, I want this to behave like this only on a specific product ID.

Which hook is suitable for this?

Comment: Howdy! Can you please provide an example of your code that you're having issues with?

Comment: There is no code, the functionality is built into WooCommerce. Just try to add a stock product to the cart and you'll see that it's adding up on top of the quantity.

Comment: Hey @7uc1f3r, I have read this and will make sure to ask better-explained questions in the future, explaining what I've tried and what didn't work. However, I see that you got my question correctly and also gave an answer that works perfectly. So thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`woocommerce_add_to_cart`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#1106) hook

In this example, product id `30` is used

```php
function action_woocommerce_add_to_cart ( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ) {
    // Get current product id
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;

    // Specific product ID, compare
    if ( $product_id == 30 ) {
        // Set quantity
        WC()->cart->set_quantity( $cart_item_key, $quantity );      
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'action_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 10, 6 );
```